# React components dynamic layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a shared package/library where stores shared components between two application. these shared components might have some feature differences based on each application. For each application which consumes these components I want to design a layout configuration. and map through the config and render components. Here is my proposal config:

```js
  const configLayout = {
    actionBar: [
      {
        component: TableUserSearchField,
        props: ['onSearchUser', 'users'],
      },
      {
        component: TablePartnerFilter,
        props: ['partnerInfo', 'project']
      },
      {
        component: TableStatusFilter,
        props: ['user', 'onClick']
        config: {
          placeholderKey:'any_selected_status',
          yesLabelKey: 'selected',
          noLabelKey: 'not_selected'
        }
      }
    ]
  };
```

is it good design to list props like that ? inside component where I map through this config, i have created an object called `propStorage` where that way I can build props object for each component

```js
const propStorage = {
  onClick,
  users,
  onSearchUser,
  ...

}
```

I will appreciate any suggestions

Comment: This is an interesting approach that I am intrigued by. Is there a reason why you are not passing the props directly for each `actionBar` item instead of having to get them from `propStorage`? Also, are you using typescript?

Comment: if I pass it directly then this config should live inside component, but I wanted to keep this in non-component file. and yes I am using typescript

Comment: Okay, I see. Could you provide some file names/paths at the top of each code block in your question above? I am wondering what file `propStorage` is defined in, and if you considered importing it into the same file as the config? But maybe this is not possible if it is tied to a component or hook?

Comment: Interesting, I was thinking about the trade-off wrt complexity, so the idea is will be  a builder like component which can take any config and return/render a React component,
is there a chance that the config will be fetched from the server or are they many types of configs to create a component,
and if there are few configs expected then creating a standard components seems ok